# MySQL find multiple occurences LIKE '%pp%' AND LIKE '%p%' to NOT match "hippo"

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like

I am trying to match keywords using multiple `LIKE`'s, however I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `keywords` WHERE keyword LIKE '%pp%' AND keyword LIKE '%p%';
```

to match "hippopotamus" but not "hippo".

I understand I can simply do:

```
SELECT * FROM `keywords` WHERE keyword LIKE '%pp%p%';
```

However I was wondering if there are any other approaches I could take. The above works fine for this example but for other examples Ill have several `OR`'s such as:

```
LIKE '%pp%p%' OR LIKE '%p%pp%' OR LIKE '%pp%p%pp%
```

etc, and it will get very messy.

Does anyone know of a prettier way of doing this?

Comment: `LIKE '%pp%' AND keyword LIKE '%p%'` Will always return the same rows .. As `%p%` is inside `%pp%` twice.  so just searching `%p%` will suffice in this case

Comment: yes thats the issue im having, I only want to return keywords with a double-p AND  singular p

Comment: I think you are possibly wanting an `OR` statement here instead of an `AND` ..  The `AND` makes no sense in this case ..

Comment: if i did: `WHERE keyword LIKE '%pp%' OR keyword LIKE '%p%'` then I would get 'pot' returned. 'pot' doesnt have a p AND a double-p. hence I want to match 'hiPPoPotamus' but NOT 'hiPPo'

Comment: What are rules, 2 `p`s in column and then a single `p`; single p and double p anywhere in string? Can you add more details about "other examples"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with `REGEXP`, like so:

```
SELECT * FROM `keywords` WHERE keyword REGEXP '([^p]|^)p([^p]|$)' AND keyword LIKE '%pp%';
```

Tests and explanation: (MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE)

```
drop table if exists keywords;
create table keywords(
keyword varchar(50)
);
insert into keywords values("hippo");
insert into keywords values("hippopotamus");
insert into keywords values("zpp");
insert into keywords values("zp");
insert into keywords values("zpzpp");
insert into keywords values("zppzp");
insert into keywords values("zppzpzzzzzppzppzp");
insert into keywords values("p");
insert into keywords values("pp");
SELECT * FROM `keywords` WHERE keyword REGEXP '([^p]|^)p([^p]|$)'; -- Returns words with 'p' that isn't 'pp'
SELECT * FROM `keywords` WHERE keyword LIKE '%pp%'; -- Returns words with 'pp'
SELECT * FROM `keywords` WHERE keyword REGEXP '([^p]|^)p([^p]|$)' AND keyword LIKE '%pp%'; -- Combine to get desired effect
-- Should only get 'hippopotamus' 'zpzpp' 'zppzp' and 'zppzpzzzzzppzppzp'
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using MySQL REGEXP here, smth like this:

```
WHERE keyword REGEXP '(?=^.*?[^p](p)[^p].*?$)(?=^.*?[^p](p{2})[^p].*?$)'
```

haven't tested, but it should be true only if `p` and `pp` are occured at the same time in any order

Comment: I don't think MySQL supports lookahead, maybe newer versions do?

Comment: try "puppy", your regex did not work.

Comment: ahh... sorry, forgot to check mysql capabilities